# Can't access subdirectories of /var/www/html

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, server, apache2

I've seen people with similar issues to this, but I've looked almost everywhere and not a single solution seems to work for me.

The short story: I'm trying to give PHP access to a subdirectory, so it can use readdir() and list a bunch of files in a subdirectory.

The only problem is that when trying to view this subdirectory in a browser, as JUST the subdirectory, it returns `403 - Forbidden`.

I'm using a Raspberry-Pi 3 to run the local web server, and it's configured to work with Apache 2, among other programs (i.e. PHP, mySQL, etc, but I don't think that matters)

Things I've tried so far:

- Giving read/execute permissions recursively in the `/var/www/html` directory, using `chmod -R a+rx /var/www/html`.
- Creating a .htaccess file containing `Options Indexes` AND `Options +Indexes` (neither of which seem to work)
- Modifying the owner of the html directory recursively to `www-data` (which is probably a terrible idea, but since I haven't forwarded port 80, it wasn't a terrible worry for me. I also DID change it back to `root:root`, which is ALSO 
  a security flaw I've heard, but that's for later).
- I restarted Apache 2 using `service apache2 restart` each time I changed something.

I'm SURE it's something simple which I don't know about.

I'm relatively new to web hosting: I'm acquainted with the basics, so please take it easy haha.

Any advice will be very much appreciated!

Comment: Could you include your Apache config for the virtual host?

Comment: You were right to have the owner `chown` be `www-data`  ---  You also need to add your current user to `www-data` group to be able to upload to the web directory.   --  Also as @Dan said, we'll need to see your Virtaul Hosts configuration file ..

Comment: @Zak, I don't see any indication he had to _write_ to the directory, just read I think.

Comment: @DanFarrell https://pastebin.com/HxmjvjuY - my apache2.conf file

Comment: @DanFarrell Yes, it was just to read from the directory, or if necessary, for whatever reason, execution (of course, I'm fairly new to all of this, so I wouldn't know too much)

Comment: Is there a configuration in sites-enabled too?

Comment: @DanFarrell there's 000-default.conf which I haven't modified at all. I'll get that up on pastebin in a second

Comment: @DanFarrell https://pastebin.com/MvShzLDs

Comment: Cool... That's probably what's actually defining the site you're hitting.

Comment: @DanFarrell Ah, fair dos. Again, all of these configuration files are almost completely alien to me so far

Comment: Ok, those all look fine.  Can you include the output of `ls -la /var/www/html` ?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/ZKkUPcZD

Comment: As i turns out, the owner isn't root. I thought I changed it back...

Comment: You  need this in your virtual host

<Directory /var/www/html>
  Options +Indexes
</Directory>

see https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/DirectoryListings

Comment: @LouisWatson Forgive me for being a bit clueless, but do you mean in the apache2.conf file or the 000-default.conf file?

Comment: @LouisWatson after looking at the link you showed me, I added 
`<Directory /var/www/html/web/pages>
  Options +Indexes
</Directory>`

Where `/web/pages` is the directory I'm trying to allow listings for.
This still doesn't work.
I also tried reassigning the owner html recursively to www-data again, but to no success.

Comment: sorry in the 000-default.conf, that is your virtual host file that needs to go inside the <VirtualHost ..> tag in that file.

Comment: "Require all granted"

try adding that on a line inside the directory tag without quotes
also the trailing slash is required so web/pages/ not web/pages

also i noticed on your persmissions when you used chown did you use the -R argument to modify child permissions also?

Comment: @LouisWatson yeah still no luck unfortunately. However, this may possibly help you; this comes up when trying `service apache2 restart` (as root user):
`Job for apache2.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status apache2.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.` I can't access either command

Comment: may i see your host file as it is now?

Comment: Just to avoid any confusion, I'll be posting apache2.conf and 000-default.conf (in that order) here:
https://pastebin.com/EmueF7ts
https://pastebin.com/3tD1EZHv

Comment: https://pastebin.com/c62rHDhm hmm ok ill check the conf

Comment: try apachectl status in your shell see if that gives you anything

Comment: /usr/sbin/apachectl: 113: /usr/sbin/apachectl: www-browser: not found
'www-browser -dump http://localhost:80/server-status' failed.
Maybe you need to install a package providing www-browser or you
need to adjust the APACHE_LYNX variable in /etc/apache2/envvars
@LouisWatson

Comment: type "cd /var/log/apache2" then "cat error.log" that will give you your error

Comment: @LouisWatson the latest error is from the 1st, so something's definitely off...

`[Mon Jan 01 19:01:42.340206 2018] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 560] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down`

Comment: And as a turn of events, I typed '1' instead of 'l' when doing `systemctl`. So yeah, I'm a blundering idiot.

Comment: `Jan 05 00:45:07 numbernineteen apachectl[1320]: AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
Jan 05 00:45:07 numbernineteen systemd[1]: apache2.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
Jan 05 00:45:07 numbernineteen systemd[1]: apache2.service: Unit entered failed state.
Jan 05 00:45:07 numbernineteen systemd[1]: apache2.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.`

Comment: At this point I might just reinstall apache2, I think it would save all of the trouble haha

Comment: lol no worries, its confusing as hell at the best of times :) that last error is just apache shutting down will be whats before that if there's anything.

Comment: Nah before that it's just the previous shutdown message. I'll just reinstall Apache2. Thanks for all your help though, I did actually learn a thing or two lol

Comment: your welcome, and yes i was going to suggest that lol, good luck. I did find this if its any help https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/41867/raspi-wont-start-apache2-after-i-power-cycled